# Type <sometype> is not enumerable

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a list that I would like to be able to enumerate so I can do foreach and similar things.

The class (Symbol.WPAN.Bluetooth.RemoteDevices) has array like notation (ie this[1])

Is there anyway to wrap this up and make it enumerable?

(By the way, I know I can just use a normal for loop instead of a foreach loop.  I guess this question is somewhat academic in nature.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming it also has a Count function you could do the following

```
public static IEnumerable<RemoteDevice> MakeEnumerable(this RemoteDevices devices) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < devices.Count; i++ ){
    yield return devices[i];
  }
}
```

A more generic solution would be the following

```
public static IEnumerable<TItem> MakeEnumerable<TSource,TItem>(
  this TSource source, 
  Func<TSource,int,TItem> getItem,
  Func<TSource,int> getCount) {
  var count = getCount(source);
  for ( var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    yield return getItem(source,i);
  }
}

...
var devices = GetTheDevicesInstance();
var e = devices.MakeEnumerable((s,i) => s[i], (s) => s.Count);
```